# MS Word 2010: don't close frame around text at page end

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, border

I have a put a border/frame around a text paragraph, that spans over 3 pages. It is a code sample. The frame has a vertical line at the top of the paragraph on the first page, then 2 vertical lines at the sides of the paragraph also on the first page, and then an unwanted horizontal line inside the paragraph at the end of the 1st page. So, the frame is closed at the end of this page, although the code sample continues on the next.
Same procedure at the 2nd page, it starts with the horizontal frame line, although the paragraph has started at the previous page.

Using a 1-cell table is not an option either, it also has the unwanted horizontal lines at page ends/beginnings.

Is there any option to avoid the closing of the frame at page ends and "reopening" at page beginnings? I only want the vertical lines as long as the paragraph has not ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a 3-cell table as a workaround. Remove border at the top and bottom for the whole table. Then add top border for the first cell and bottom border for the last cell. Decrease height of the first and third cell and put text inside second cell. I tested this and it works.